# Let $G= G_1 * G_2$, where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are cyclic of orders $m$ and $n$. Then $m$ and $n$ are uniquely determined by $G$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, free-groups, free-product

I'm having trouble understanding the following problem from Munkres' Topology. I have shown (a) and (b) below, for (b) I got $k=\max(m,n)$, but I don't know what I need to prove for (c). In fact, what does it mean that $m$ and $n$ are uniquely determined by $G$?

[image]

Comment: what is $G*G$??

Comment: It is the free product.

Comment: You know $mn$ and $\max(m,n)$. Isn't the other number equal to $mn/\max(m,n)$?

Comment: Why is that? Sorry I don't understand your reasoning.

Comment: Any element of finite order in a free product is a conjugate of an element in one of the free factors, so the answer to (b) is $\max(m,n)$. What you have to prove in (c) is that if $C_m*C_n \cong C_{m'}*C_{n'}$ then $\{m,n\}=\{m',n'\}$, and this follows from (a) and (b).

Answer (score 0):

I won't write a full proof. But it basically goes as follows.

For (a), any member of $G$ is of the form $x^{\alpha_1}y^{\beta_1}x^{\alpha_2}y^{\beta_2} \cdots$, where $x$ is the generator of $G_1$ and $y$ is the generator of $G_2$. Its corresponding element in $G/[G,G]$ is $$(x^{\alpha_1}y^{\beta_1}x^{\alpha_x}y^{\beta_2} \dots) [G,G] = 
(x^{\alpha_1}[G,G]) (y^{\beta_1}[G,G]) (x^{\alpha_2}[G,G]) (y^{\beta_2}[G,G]) \cdots).$$

Since $G/[G,G]$ is abelian, we can reorder the factors on the RHS and this gives us $(x^\alpha y^\beta) [G,G]$. It is easy to show that $(x^\alpha y^\beta) [G,G] = (x^{\alpha'} y^{\beta'}) [G,G]$ if and only if $\alpha=\alpha' \mod{m}$ and $\beta=\beta' \mod{n}$.

For (b), Exercise 68.2 shows that an element of G either (i) does not have ﬁnite order or (ii) has the same order of elements of $G_1$ and $G_2$ that have finite order. Therefore $k = \max (m,n)$.

(c) Since both $mn$ and $\max (m,n)$ are uniquely determined by $G$, $m$ and $n$ are uniquely determined by $G$.